# Atmega8 Timer 2 not working

Tags: avr

I am using Atmega8 with 16 MHz clock and use Timer2 as PWM with this code

```
DDRB |= (1 << DDB3);
OCR2 = 0;
TCCR2 |= (1 << COM21);
TCCR2 |= (1 << WGM21) | (1 << WGM20);
TCCR2 |= (1 << CS21);
OCR2 = 0;
```

but after this code 0 PWM my led was start with low brightness. So please give me solution.

Comment: Hast been also asked [at Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/86981/16051).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set OCR2 as 0 it doesn't mean that it will be no pwm signal.
Actually it will make little peaks in beginning of every PWM cycle. To turn pwm off you should disable PWM on timer.